# keycloaker logout using passport js and SAML workflow

Tags: keycloak, passport.js, saml

How to logout from a IDP provider
using SAML and passport JS
in my case I am using Keycloak as a IDP provider

I also have a logout Url
plzz tell me how do I hit the logout url using passport js ,
and what i need to send in the payload